# Trigger event not working jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers

I want to simulate a click on the a link that is in the li next to the li with a.active in it when the user clicks on the a.test link, but for some reason my jquery code is not working. Any ideas?

JQUERY

```
$('a.test').click(function() {
    $('a.active').parent().parent().next().find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="test">link</a>

<ul>
<li id="">
<div class="page">
<a class="active" href="javascript:function Z(){Z=""}Z()">1</a>
</div>
</li>
<li id="">
<div class="page">
<a class="" href="javascript:function Z(){Z=""}Z()">2</a>
</div>
</li>
<li id="">
<div class="page">...</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not bind click event on a tag on which you want to trigger the click event, just bind that and your code will work.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/NybHT/4/)**

```
$('a.test').click(function () {
    $('a.active').parent().parent().next().find('a').trigger('click');  
});

$('li a').click(function () {  
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your click event in `doc ready` handler: [*get* **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWdaa/)

```
$(function(){
   $('a.test').click(function() {
      $('a.active').parent().parent().next().find('a').trigger('click');
   });
});
```

`and make sure to call the jquery library first.`

Comment: thanks, how can I make it do whatever the a should so when it is clicked. In this case it's a pagination and would show the next page. So I want it to really simulate a click of that a link.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the click event handler in your jquery scope not in the html as it is

+you should use `.on('click','subselector',function(){})`

+your Z function doesn't do anything anyway except emptying Z that is not even declare as a variable... so even it the click is triggered nothing will happen

Comment: thanks, how can I make it do whatever the a should do so when it is clicked. In this case it's a pagination and would show the next page. So I want it to really simulate a click of that a link.

Comment: `window.location(this.href)`

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/FmASe/

```
$('a.test').click(function () {
  $('a.active').closest('li').next().find('a').trigger('click');
});

$('li a').click(function () {  
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Just bind the click event..